# Issue with % operator in C

Tags: c, math, percentage

I am having an issue with the % operator in C.  I know that the % operator gives the remainder of a division.  However when faced with a question like `1 % 2` or `3 % 2`, I get confused.  After googling this, I found different solutions.

Some say that as `1 / 2` is `0.5`, we round it down to 0.  So `1 % 2` is 0.

Others say that as `1 / 2` is `0.5`, we instead round it up, like we would in maths, to 1.  So `1 % 2` is 1.

And therefore, I am now confused.  My question is:  **What is 1 % 2?**

Thank you in advance :):)

Comment: For M % D, whenever M < D, then the answer will be M.

Comment: @Jim I think you want "0 <= M < D", else you assertion is easily disproved.

Comment: @chux, yes for the above assertion to be true, M and D need to be greater than 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, both are wrong methods.  As you said `%` finds the remainder of division.

Therefore 1/2 is equal to 0 remainder 1.

And the answer is thus 1.

Also, to experiment yourself, you could have used this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int remainder;

    remainder = 1 % 2;
    printf("1 %% 2 is %d", remainder);
    return(0);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

`%` is the remainder operator:

> The % operator computes the **remainder after dividing its first operand
>   by its second**.

It's what left from the division. For example:

5 % 3 is 2.
5 % 4 is 1.
5 % 2 is 1. (Because 2 can fit 2 times in 5, 1 will be left)

When you do 1 % 2 the result is 1 because 1/2 is 0, and the remainder is.. 1.

Comment: This makes no sence. Edit your second line. :)

Comment: To be pedantic, `%` is the **remainder** operator in C.  There's an important difference (vs. the mathematical definition of modulo) for negative operands.

Comment: @MarounMaroun When you do 1 % 2 the result is 1 , please change.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to think of M % D (if both M and D are positive) is:

```
While ( M >= D){
    M = M-D;
}
return M;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no rounding, the decimal part is simply truncated.

So, **1 / 2** is 0 and **1 % 2** is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need the mathematical definition on remainder.

Given two integer numbers *m, d*, we say that *r* is the **remainder** of the division of *m* and *d* if *r* satisfies two conditions:

- There exists another integer *k* such that `m == k * d + r` , and
- `0 <= r < d`.

In C we have `m % d == r` and `m / d == k`, just by following the definition above.
As you can see, there is no trucation at all (I mean: the "truncation" is consequence of the definition).

From the definition, it can be obtainded that 3 % 2 == 1 and 3 / 2 == 1.
Other examples:

> 4 / 3 == 1  and 5 / 3 == 1, in despite of 5.0/3.0 == 1.6666 (which
>   would round to 2.0).
>
> 4 % 3 == 1  and 5 % 3 == 2.

You can trust also in the formula `r = m - k * d`, which in C is written as:

`m % d == m - (m / d) * d`

However, in the standard C, the integer division follows the rule: `round to 0`.
Thus, with negative operands C offer different results that the mathematical ones.
We would have:

> (-4) / 3 == -1, (-4) % 3 == -1 (in C), but in plain maths: (-4) / 3 = -2, (-4) % 3 = 2.

In plain maths, the remainder is always nonnegative, and less than the `abs(d)`.
In standard C, the remainder always has the sign of the first operator.

Remark: This description (in the negative case) is for standard C99/C11 only. You must be carefull with your compiler version, and to do some tests.